# Counterexample in integrable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am studying integrable functions, and I am looking for a few counterexamples for some proofs, but struggling at one: Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Is there a sequence $(f_n)$ where $\sum_{n\geq 1} |\int f_nd\mu|<\infty$; $g(x):=\sum_{n\geq 1}f_n(x)$ is well defined (in the sense that is absolutely convergent), but $g$ is not integrable?

Answer (score 0):

$f_n(x)=x$ if $n \leq |x|<n+1$ and $0$ otherwise. (Here $g(x)=x$ for all $x$).